# Instance type from ansible ec2_remote_facts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using `ec2_remote_facts` module in ansible to retrieve all AWS EC2 instances procured by different users. But the instance type i.e `c3.large` or `m1.small` is not available in the information returned. How can I access the instance type? (It is available in the EC2-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance type is not returned by [ec2_remote_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_remote_facts_module.html).

One way to get this is to monkey patch your ansible. Go to your ansible install directory. If you don't know where it is, try:

```
python -c 'import ansible; print locals()'
```

Edit `modules/extras/cloud/amazon/ec2_remote_facts.py` file and add:

```
'instance_type': instance.instance_type,
```

to `instance_info` directory in method `get_instance_info()`. Now you can see instance type is returned.

```
        "image_id": "ami-46b122622",
        "instance_type": "t2.small",
        "launch_time": "2016-11-14T21:14:44.000Z",
```